# upload more files to a folder with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload

I try to upload multiple files to an specific folder using laravel. I was able to do this with just one file. But after I tried to upload multiple files it didn't work. First of all I tried to make an foreach. But it didn't work I tried to find solutions on the internet but unfortunately I didn't find one. Can anybody help me?

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  // dd(request()->all());

  $this->validate(request(), [
    'name' => 'required|unique:lessons|max:20',
    'type' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'price' => 'required',
    'main_picture' => 'required',
    'pictures' => 'required'
  ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    $images= array();

    if($files=$request->file('images')){
      foreach($files as $file){
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('lesson images',$name);
        $images[]=$name;
      }
    }

    $lesson = Lesson::create( [
      'name' =>$input['name'],
      'type' => $input['type'],
      'description' =>$input['description'],
      'price' => $input['price'],
      'main_picture' =>$input['main_picture'],
      'pictures'=>  implode("|",$images),
    ]);

    $image_name = $request->file('main_picture')->getClientOriginalName();

    $id = $lesson->id;


    if($request->hasFile('main_picture')) {
      $file = $request->file('main_picture');
      $file->move('lesson images', $id . "-main-" . $image_name);
    }

    return redirect('/lessenoverzicht');

}
```

HTML:

```
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/lessenoverzicht/toevoegen">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name"><span class='required'>*</span>Naam les:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Voer naam les in..">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"><span class='required'>*</span>Type</label>
      <select name='type' class="form-control" id="type">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
        <option value='les'>Les</option>
        <option value='workshop'>Workshop</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description"><span class='required'>*</span>Omschrijving:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" rows="10" placeholder="Voer omschrijving in..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <label for="description"><span class='required'>*</span>Prijs:</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">

      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">€</span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" value="0.00" min="0" step="1.00" class="form-control" id='price' name='price'>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="main_picture"><span class='required'>*</span>Main Image:</label>
      <input type="file" class='form-control' id='main_picture' name="main_picture">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="picture">Afbeelding(en) omschrijving:</label>
      <input type="file" class='form-control' id='picture' name="pictures" multiple>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      @include('layouts.errors')
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Toevoegen</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML part too? It seems you have not created array of input type file in the HTML

Comment: I just added the HTML

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below change in your code? I have only added `Array` type `name` property `name="pictures[]"`

`<input type="file" class='form-control' id='picture' name="pictures[]" multiple>`

**Sample Code:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/details">
```

and this for multiple selection:

```
<input required type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" placeholder="address" multiple>
```

**PHP logic**

```
public function store(request $request) {

    $input=$request->all();
    $images=array();
    if($files=$request->file('images')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('image',$name);
            $images[]=$name;
        }
    }
    /*Insert your data*/

    Detail::insert( [
        'images'=>  implode("|",$images),
        'description' =>$input['description'],
        //you can put other insertion here
    ]);


    return redirect('redirecting page');
}
```

Comment: Do I also have to change $picture_name = $request->file('pictures')->getClientOriginalName() to $picture_name = $request->file('pictures[]')->getClientOriginalName()?

Comment: No, Keep your logic as it is.

Comment: ok. I get the following error: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `lessons` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `price`, `main_picture`, `pictures`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (f, les, g, 234, C:\xampp\tmp\phpBD2.tmp, C:\xampp\tmp\phpBE3.tmp, 2018-07-29 10:32:41, 2018-07-29 10:32:41))

Comment: Change this `$picture_name = $request->file('pictures')->getClientOriginalName();` to `$picture_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();`

Comment: Have you referenced my sample code? I think you missed to change the request name. `if($files=$request->file('images')){` it should be `if($files=$request->file('pictures')){` in your case. and avoid space between the 
`lesson images` in the statement `$file->move('lesson images',$name);`

Comment: Yes I forgot to do that. Now it works. Thank you very much